# Center title over section with multiple image?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Im have a section (StyledHead) where im mapping out 10 images from an api. I have another section (StyledHeader) wrapping it where I also have a h1. How do I center the h1 both ways so its center over the images?

Styling:

```
const StyledHeader = styled.header`
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
`;

const StyledHead = styled.section`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```

The code:

```
<StyledHeader>
        <h1>Sidetittel</h1>
        {loading ? <p>laster...</p> : null}
        <StyledHead>
          {data.Search?.length > 0
            ? data.Search.slice(0, 10).map((items) => (
                <img key={uuid()} alt="filmplakat" src={items.Poster} />
              ))
            : null}
        </StyledHead>
      </StyledHeader>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try to set h1 position to absolute or fixed and try to center it in the middle of the parent element.

If you would like to center something in the middle of the screen, you should do it like this:

```
h1 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

but if you need it to be the middle of the parent element you have to change top and left properties to margin or padding probably.

Comment: Aboslute position works along with top/left values. Only issue different screen sizes, then the h1 is all over the place..